# Is a given set of group elements a set of coset representatives?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

I am afraid the question is a bit technical, but I hope someone might have stumbled into a similar subject, or give me a pointer of some kind.

If G is a group (in the sense of algebraic structure), and if g<sub>1</sub>, ..., g<sub>n</sub> are elements of G, is there an algorithm (or a function in some dedicated program, like GAP) to determine whether there is a subgroup of G such that those elements form a set of representatives for the cosets of the subgroup? (We may assume that G is a permutation group, and probably even the full symmetric group.)

(There are of course several algorithms to find the cosets of a given subgroups, like Todd-Coxeter algorithm; this is a kind of inverse question.)

Thanks,
Daniele

Comment: This makes me wish I could immediately recall my Abstract Algebra classes...

Comment: To whoever voted to close: Jeez, the guy is asking about an ALGORITHM. Last I checked, an algorithm was something used in programming.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can come up with is naive.  Basically if you have elements `x1,...,xn`, you would use GAP's `LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup` to enumerate all subgroups with index n (discarding those with index < n).  Then you would go through each such group, generate the cosets, and check that each coset contains one of the elements.

This is all I could think of.  I would be very interested if you came up with a better approach.

Comment: To do things this way, you'd have to generate a presentation for G. LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup only works for finitely presented groups.

Comment: Yes that is an undischarged assumption.  I would be very interested in finding a proper solution to this problem

Comment: Il-Bhima, tahnks for your answer. I hope for something slightly less "brute force".
I have briefly flirted with Schreier's Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%27s_subgroup_lemma), but apparently it is used to obtain a generating set for a "known" group, say a stabiliser.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to determine is if there is a subgroup H of G such that {g<sub>1</sub>, ..., g<sub>n</sub>} is a [transversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversa) of the cosets of H. i.e. A set of representatives of the partitioning of G by the cosets of H.

First, by [Lagrange's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) theorem, |G| = |G:H| * |G|, where |G:H| = |G|/|H| is the index of the subgroup H of G. If {g<sub>1</sub>, ..., g<sub>n</sub>} is indeed a transversal, then |G:H| = |{g<sub>1</sub>, ..., g<sub>n</sub>}|, so the first test in your algorithm should be whether n divides |G|.

Moreover, since g<sub>i</sub> and g<sub>j</sub> are in the same right coset only if g<sub>i</sub>g<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup> is in H, you can then check subgroups with index n to see if they avoid g<sub>i</sub>g<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup>. Also, note that (g<sub>i</sub>g<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup>)(g<sub>j</sub>g<sub>k</sub><sup>-1</sup>) = g<sub>i</sub>g<sub>k</sub><sup>-1</sup>, so you can choose any pairing of the g<sub>i</sub>s.

This should be sufficient if n is small compared to |G|.

Another approach is to start with H being the trivial group and add elements of the set H<sup>*</sup> = {h in G : h<sup>k</sup> != g<sub>i</sub>g<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup>, for all i, j, k; i != j} to the generators of H until you can't add any more (i.e. until it's no longer a subgroup). H is then a maximal subgroup of G such that H is a subset of H<sup>*</sup>. If you can get all such H (and have them be large enough) then the subgroup you're looking for must be one of them.

This approach would work better for larger n.

Either way a non-exponential-time approach isn't obvious.

**EDIT:** I've just found a discussion of this very topic here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2009_April_18#Is_a_given_set_of_group_elements_a_set_of_coset_representatives.3F

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less brute approach would be to enumerate all subgroups of index n, as Il-Bhima suggested, and then for each subgroup, check each x<sub>i</sub> * x<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup> to see if it is contained in the subgroup.

The elements x1, ..., xn will be representatives for a subgroup if and only if EVERY product

x<sub>i</sub> * x<sub>j</sub><sup>-1</sup> where  (i != j)

is NOT in the subgroup.

This type of check seems both simpler than generating all cosets, and computationally faster.